# FQL search public posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search, facebook-fql

I'm trying to do a search using FQL.
Using the Graph API, it works but there are more options using FQL.
Using something like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=myquery&access_token=mytoken
```

it work fine.

I'm looking for the equivalent in FQL.

What query I must write in here

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20post_id%2C%20actor_id%2C%20target_id%2C%20message%20FROM%20stream&access_token=mytoken
```

The query above give me that

```
Parser error: unexpected end of query
```

I want to search in all public posts.
I've been looking everywhere but I did not found any solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For searching public posts for a string, you need to use the Graph API, and then filter those posts in your script. I don't think searching all public posts is possible in FQL. While FQL is more powerful, it is also more limited.

You are getting an error because you don't have a "WHERE" clause in your query. This is required in FQL.

The limit comes in because you must use at least one indexed column in your WHERE query. For the stream table you must specify either a post via `post_id`, a user via `source_id` or `filter_key`, or a live stream via `xid`. The indexed fields are marked with a `*` on the documentation site.

For instance, [this FQL][1]

```
SELECT post_id,actor_id,target_id,message FROM stream WHERE filter_key = 'others' 
   AND strpos(message, 'the') >= 0
```

will get you all posts that show on your access token owner's wall that have not been posted by the owner, with the string 'the' in them. That is the best you can get. If the post isn't visible on their wall, then you won't get the post.

If you try to leave out an indexed field, FQL will throw a 'Your statement is not indexable' error.

[1]: SELECT post_id,actor_id,target_id,message FROM stream WHERE filter_key = 'others' and strpos(message,'the') >=0

Comment: Ok. I got it. In this case, do you know if I can add some criteria using Graph API like updated_time>xxxxx ?

Comment: According to the FQL stream documentation "Querying by updated_time is currently not supported". Once you have one indexable field in your WHERE clause, you can add as many different additional conditions as you want using `AND` and `OR` statements.

Comment: Works for me: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3D%22Jethro%20Tull%22%26type%3Dpost%26updated_time%3E1347494400

Comment: Version note: Searching public post is no longer available since Graph API v2.0. Only approved media agent can use a new API called Public Feed API to search public posts.